# IF-condition on a Yes/No column value

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I have a SharePoint list where I'm creating a custom galley view. The list contains a yes/no column (named *isOwner*) which defines if a listed team member is owner or not.

In the JSON for the galley view I now want to display text according to the setting in the yes/no column. If the value is set to yes (true) it should write 'Captain', else 'Crew'. But it always displays 'Crew' no matter which condition I choose.

My code so far:

```
"txtContent": "=if([$isOwner] == true, 'Captain', 'Crew')"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
"txtContent": "=if([$isOwner], 'Captain', 'Crew')"
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: So quick and easy. Thx